# can gtk.LinkButton do a POST request?

Tags: pygtk

I am working at a GPL botanical collection manager ([bauble](http://github.com/Bauble/bauble.classic)), and I am linking to some reference sites like the wikipedia, [the plant list](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search), and similar sites.

all the above handle requests as GET and for each of them I'm generating an URI which I am connecting to a gtk.LinkButton.

is it possible to link to sites only handling requests as POST? I'm wondering because I had to link to [tropicos](http://tropicos.org/), and initially I had not found the way they handle GET requests.

Comment: It looks like you can use GET requests for tropicos as well.

Comment: agreed. »initially« I had not found it, but even with this as a working solution, I am still wondering if and how to do a POST request from a gtk.LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working with pygtk any more.  and I guess that if I still needed this (I don't), I should consider [this](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/LinkButton.html#Gtk.LinkButton): »By default, Gtk.LinkButton calls Gtk.show_uri_on_window() when the button is clicked. This behaviour can be overridden by connecting to the Gtk.LinkButton ::activate-link signal and returning True from the signal handler.«